# Configuração do PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tentando acessar meu banco de dados do meu PostgreSQL, porém estou tendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma máquina virtual **Debian 8** com **postgreSQL 9.4** instalada e estou tentando acessar via meu Windows 7.

Fiz alterações nos meus arquivos **pg_hba.conf** e **postgresql.conf**, porém sem sucesso.

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
local   all         postgres                          ident sameuser

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
host    all        all         192.168.0.0/24         md5

local   all         all                               ident sameuser
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Tente adicionando a seguinte linha: `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` e reinicie o PostgreSQL

Comment: Olá, eu mudei a linha porém continua dando o erro. Essa linha liberaria acesso para todos os acessos, correto? Será que pode ser algum bloqueio da porta 5432? Ou não tem nada a ver?

Comment: Pode ser que sim, mas a porta está mesmo aberta? Esse comando lista as portas abertas: `netstat -nl`

Comment: @Luídne dei o comando e a porta 5432 não apareceu na listagem, como faço pra abrir?

Comment: O serviço pode não estar executando. Verifique usando o comando `service postgres status` e se não estiver executando use o comando `service postgres start` e verifique novamente a porta.

Comment: Experimenta rodar o [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) a partir do Windows pra ver se a sua máquina virtual está expondo a porta 5432 — provavelmente você precisa abrir a porta pra conseguir acessar o PostgreSQL a partir do Windows (como fazer isso depende do programa de virtualização: VMWare, VirtualBox, …).

Comment: @Luídne, consegui fazer funcionar, quando você disse pra eu verificar o `service postgres status`, percebi que estava desativado. Desinstalei o postgre e instalei novamente na esperança de começar tudo de novo e dar certo, e com isso vi que a porta 5432 estava aberta com o postgre recém instalado. Ao mexer na configuração do **pg_hba.conf** percebi que a porta parava de aparecer no netstat. Então descobri que na verdade o erro estava no arquivo que fazia a porta sumir. Com a linha `host    all             all             192.168.0.0/0           trust` consegui fazer ela funcionar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do Luídne descobri que meu arquivo **pg_hba.conf** estava fazendo a porta 5432 do postgre não ficar aberta quando dava o comando `netstat -nl`.

Reinstalei o postgresql no meu debian e dei o comando netstat. Com isso a porta 5432 estava aberta com o postgresql nas configurações padrões. Ao editar o arquivo **pg_hba.conf** novamente percebi que a porta deixava de ficar aberta, isso me leva a crer que pode ser que eu estava com algum erro no arquivo.

Com o arquivo **pg_hba.conf** desta maneira, tudo funcionou normalmente:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/0           trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```